# IOS memory and battery management - Memory vs Work

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to IOS and coming from pcs I am trying to get a feel for managing memory and battery resources.

I have a UIImageView subclass which is is very light (it's an image placeholder with a handful of methods). This subClass is repeatedly added to, and removed from, several root views. I hold an IBOutlet reference to the subClass on each root view.

Would you:

- Simply add/remove the subClass from the root view (and keep it in memory)?

Or

- Create and destroy the subClass instance each time (freeing the memory but extra work)?

Is this worth considering or am I worrying over nothing?

Would your answer be the same if the UIImageView subClass was very large?

Is there a way of measuring these matters?

Comment: I'd say keep the instance, since you're using it repeatedly.  If you are really concerned, you can always profile your app in Instruments to find any leaks, and if it is on a device, you can still use Instruments to measure battery consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with your first option, keeping it in memory. This is just because I think it is handy to keep my views alive and reuse them. This means that they will remember their state and content and that helps out in many cases. I usually write methods to reset the content or refresh it when needed.

Keeping it in memory might also increase the loading of the view slightly, but usually you do not notice the difference, and I see people using both ways.

And yes, I would say you are worrying a bit too much, especially if you think this decision would affect battery.

Regarding memory management, keeping the imageview in memory or releasing/recreating consumes the exact same amount of memory as long as you only have one imageview that you are using. The only difference is that you are allocating and releasing it repeatedly if you are recreating it.

You could however get memory issues if you start creating new imageviews every time the user opens them and never letting go of them, but that means you are doing something fundamentally wrong in your programming.

As long as you know what you are doing, no need to worry about the amount of memory in a case like this - there's plenty. Start worrying if you are handling large images.

Especially if you use ARC there is not much to worry about, just start hacking away. If you are managing memory manually, I do recommend trying to reuse stuff because that causes less headache and risk of giant leaking. Use leaktools and analyze tool to make sure in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use `UIImageView` with disregard on iOS.  `UIImageView` is not much more than a clipping region with some methods for dealing with images.

The resource which takes up more memory is the `UIImage` contained by the `UIImageView` and these are cached by iOS.

So there is little cost to creating `UIImageViews` and destroying them, just take care that you dealloc them and don't leak memory and you should be fine unless you have hundreds of them.

The subclass being "large" doesnt matter, the code in a class is never loaded more than once.  If the class has alot of extra state - that will take up some memory but I cant image a whole lot of that in a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

You better just keep it in memory. User experience will be much better if you don't slow down the device by continuously recreating the image view. One single poor UIImageView instance is not memory heavy enough to worth the time and effort to recreaty all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it an memory to improve performance isn't as much of a hit as you would think - taken from the other answers you have. But you should remove it from memory if you get a memory warning, and provide a way to bring it back to life as needed.